# Python coroutine creating infinity number of new threads

Tags: python, discord.py

So, i have a discord bot running on a server (Django, python 3.7, centos).
Bot looks like this:

```
*imports*

ready = 0

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    global ready
    ready = 1
    print("bot is ready")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('$A'):
        await message.channel.send('A!')
    if message.content.startswith('$B'):
        await message.channel.send('B!')
    if message.content.startswith('$C'):
        await message.channel.send('C!')
    ....
    if message.content.startswith('$N'):
        await message.channel.send('N!')
        
    onm = on_message(message)
    onm.close() 
    
if ready==0:
    client.run("token")
    on_ready()
```

After i do something like "python bot.py" and start my bot,
my threads looks like this (4 threads, data from threading.enumerate()) -

```
[<_MainThread(MainThread, started 139929123342144)>, 
<Thread(ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0, started daemon 139928865715968)>, 
<Thread(ThreadPoolExecutor-0_1, started daemon 139928850818816)>, 
<KeepAliveHandler(Thread-1, started daemon 139928842426112)>]
```

but after a time it becomes like this (5 threads) -

```
[<_MainThread(MainThread, started 139929123342144)>, 
<Thread(ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0, started daemon 139928865715968)>, 
<Thread(ThreadPoolExecutor-0_1, started daemon 139928850818816)>, 
<KeepAliveHandler(Thread-1, started daemon 139928842426112)>, 
<Thread(ThreadPoolExecutor-0_2, started daemon 139928625215232)>]
```

Until i got N threads, "**RuntimeError: can't start new thread**" error and bot dies.

The question is - What is my mistake?
My guess is that i need to somehow cleanup after coroutine execution,
but i cannot find example for that and Discord sample code for chat bot don't have any handling for such problem.
Do i have some kind of coroutine mistake or its the server part thing?
Is there a way to keep threads from creating or i need to delete them on time?

What i tried to do:

1. Using "asyncio.create_task":

```
asyncio.create_task(message.channel.send('N!'))
task.cancel()
await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
```

It seems to help with threads problem, but i stop receiving messages in my channel.

2. Using .kill()/.terminate() to stop threads after the amount become too big - no effect.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your bot is that you are calling the on_message function recursively within itself without any exit condition, which leads to an infinite loop and the creation of an ever-increasing number of threads. The on_message function is already a coroutine function, so there is no need to call it as a separate task.

To fix this issue, remove the line onm = on_message(message) and onm.close() from your code. Instead, let the event loop handle the execution of the coroutine function on_message.

Also, remove the line `if ready==0` and `on_ready()` from your code. The `client.run()` method will block the execution of the script until the bot is ready, and the `on_ready()` function will be automatically called when the bot is ready.

You can try this:

```
# imports

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("bot is ready")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('$A'):
        await message.channel.send('A!')
    if message.content.startswith('$B'):
        await message.channel.send('B!')
    if message.content.startswith('$C'):
        await message.channel.send('C!')
    ....
    if message.content.startswith('$N'):
        await message.channel.send('N!')

client.run("token")
```

Comment: Hell, thanks for explanation. 
I tried this solution, it doesn't change anything. 
But i found out that on other platform (windows) i don't have such threading issue and made a request to my server provider.
I think they might explain something.